# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte ... invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, pyperclip

I am currently working through a book teaching myself Python and I have come across a bug I can't seem to get a good answer for. The error is:

```
'File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 596, in lazy_load_stub_paste
    return paste()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 109, in paste_osx_pbcopy
    return stdout.decode(ENCODING)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 197: invalid start byte'
```

The problematic line of code:

```
text = str(pyperclip.paste())
```

The full script:

```
import pyperclip, re

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?               # area code
    (\s|-|\.)?                       # separator
    (\d{3})                          # first 3 digits
    (\s|-|\.)?                       # separator
    (\d{4})                          # last 4 digits
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?   #extension
)''', re.VERBOSE)

emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+                # username
    @                                # @ symbol
    [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+                   # domain name
    (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})                # dot-something
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []
for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
    phoneNum = '-'.join([groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]])
    if groups[8] != '':
        phoneNum += ' x' +groups[8]
    matches.append(phoneNum)
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])

if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
    print('Copied to clipboard:')
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('No phone numbers of email addresses found.')
```

Let me know if there is anything else I may provide to solve this. From my searching, it seems to be an encoding error, but I haven't the slightest idea how to solve it.

I appreciate any feedback.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the content of `pyperclip.paste()`?

Comment: The content is the text pulled from www.nostarch.com/contactus.htm

Comment: pyperclip.paste().encode(errors=replace)

Comment: @xaav - This did not solve the error

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: It is decode! pyperclip.paste().decode(errors=replace)

Comment: @xaav, decode did not work either. Here is the traceback:

Comment: `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 596, in lazy_load_stub_paste
    return paste()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 109, in paste_osx_pbcopy
    return stdout.decode(ENCODING)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 197: invalid start byte`

Comment: use Google to check in what encoding is char 0xa8

Comment: Seems like a bug in paperclip. Report it to them

Comment: @furas, 0xa8 is a double quote.

Comment: @xaav, Thank you, I will.

Comment: can you start from 1?..... pyperclip.paste()[1:].....? might be a workaround..

Comment: @johnashu This workaround still gave me an error.

Comment: I've reduced what was stored in 'pyperclip.paste()' and that seems to work. If I CTRL+A the entire webpage, an error appears. If I only select a few paragraphs, the script runs.

Comment: Did you report the bug? I did not see a bug report last time I checked. If you don't report it, then it won't be fixed.

Comment: @xaav, I reached out to the author but have not received a response. Where would I report the bug?

Comment: https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/issues

Comment: @xaav, Thank you. bug reported.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is calling str() on the pyperclip.paste() in python 2. This is because the contents that you are passing into str aren't ascii.
I don't really know why you'd want to call str on the pyperclip.paste(), because that seems to return a string. Also note that python 3 str() can handle this.

Comment: Eh? Read the stack trace -- the exception is from *inside the library*; it has nothing to do with casting the returned value. Also, `str()` in Python 2 is what Python 3 calls a bytestring. It doesn't *require* that contents be printable ASCII, or otherwise constrain them.

Comment: Keep in mind that a UnicodeDecodeError is trying to convert *from* a bytestring *to* a character string. If calling `str()` -- requesting a bytestring --
 caused a bug, it would be the other direction.

Comment: You're right @CharlesDuffy. There's some additional context about this one since the OP asked this question multiple times, in multiple places so I think I may have crossed some wires.

It is worth knowing, for the OP, however, that the only time I'm getting any encoding related exceptions from the contents of the website mentioned is when I call str, with the contents of pyperclip.paste() in python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding issue; remove the registered trademark symbol (next to LEGO)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for the answer, perhaps to help the original poster you could give a suggestion of how to do this.